# How to use a list comprehension to read from a function and create a new list?

Tags: python

Using list comprehension to extract all the tweets in the tweets_and_more list and save them in another list called tweets. Print the length of the resulting list. Also, print the first three elements of the new list.

```
start_tag = "<tweet>"

def extract_tweet(data):
    start = data.index("<tweet>")+len(start_tag)
    end = data.index("</tweet>")
    seq = data[start:end]
    return seq
```

This is my extract tweet function

My list with all the tweets line by line is saved in a list called "tweets_and_more"

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use List compression to do this.  I can do it using a loop I guess but any help with explanation would be great.

Comment: I did try tweets = [tweets_and_more for s in extract_tweet(tweets_and_more[s])]  but this gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

The for loop code is placed at the end

```
tweets = [extract_tweet(data) for data in tweets_and_more]
```